# Why does the applicationState publisher only publish once?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to react every time the application state changes. I'm listening to the `\.applicationState` publisher:

```
UIApplication.shared.publisher(for: \.applicationState)
  .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    switch completion {
    case .finished:
      print("finished")
    case .failure:
      print("failure")
    }
  }, receiveValue: { state in
    print("state", state.rawValue)
  })
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

However, this only fires once (but doesn't complete). If I background the app and reopen it, it doesn't publish any new values. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publisher you are using is for KVO-compliant properties. (See [Performing Key-Value Observing with Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/performing-key-value-observing-with-combine/).) But the archived [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) warns us:

> **Important:** Not all class are KVO-compliant for all properties. … Typically properties in Apple-supplied frameworks are only KVO-compliant if they are documented as such.

But the [notification center](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/) can inform us of these state changes, e.g., [`didBecomeActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification/):

```swift
NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("finished")
        case .failure:
            print("failure")
        }
    } receiveValue: { notification in
        print("notification", notification)
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Or, just:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { notification in
        print("notification", notification)
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

See [Routing Notifications to Combine Subscribers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/routing-notifications-to-combine-subscribers). See [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-key-value-observing-in-swift) for information about creating your own KVO-compliant types in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It looks [applicationstate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623003-applicationstate) like is not 'KVO-compliant'. Which means you can't use KVO to observe the property.

`NSObject.publisher(for:)` is managed by [KVO](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/Publishers%2BKeyValueObserving.swift)

To read the applicationState from single Publisher you can use multiple Notification about UI-Lifecycle like bleow.

```
    // If you have no UIScene setting on info.plist and not using SwiftUI App, this publisher is enough
    let legacyAppStatePublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
        for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: UIApplication.shared
    )
    // when didBecomeActiveNotification is dispatched, applicationState already changed to next state so read it directly
    .map{ _ in
        UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    }.merge(
        with: NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification,
            object: UIApplication.shared
        )
        // when didEnterBackgroundNotification is dispatched, applicationState already changed to next state so read it directly
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState },
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
            object: UIApplication.shared
        )
        // when willEnterForegroundNotification occurs applicationState is not changed yet, redispatch to main queue to handle it after change occurs.
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState },
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
            object: UIApplication.shared
        )
        // when willEnterForegroundNotification occurs applicationState is not changed yet, redispatch to main queue to handle it after change occurs.
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState }
    )
    // prepend initial state if you needs this
    .prepend(UIApplication.shared.applicationState)
    
    // If your app's UI is managed by UIScene, you have to use this publisher
    let modernAppStatePublisher =
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
        for: UIScene.didEnterBackgroundNotification
    )
    .map{ _ in
        UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    }
    .merge(
        with: NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIScene.didActivateNotification
        )
        // did... notification read state now
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState },
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIScene.willDeactivateNotification
        )
        // will... notification read state after notification dispatching is finished
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState },
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification
        )
        // will... notification read state after notification dispatching is finished
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map{ _ in UIApplication.shared.applicationState }
    )
    // prepend initial state if you needs this
    .prepend(UIApplication.shared.applicationState)
    // remove duplicates since UIApplicationState represents the most active scene's state
    .removeDuplicates()
```